# How do I change owner/permission to 505:507?

Tags: command-line, file-permissions, chmod, ownership

How do I change owner/permission to 505 for uid and 507 for gid.

I had tried:

```
chmod 505:507 file/folder
```

but it failed.

[image: chmod permission 0]

Comment: Dont forget sudo, unless you are logged in as root, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to change the owner/group, then you should use `chown` command instead, e.g.

```
chown -v 505:507 file/folder
```

Also note that to change the ownership, you need to run as root or prefix the command with `sudo`.

The `chmod` is for changing the file/folder permissions.